# How to derive a new Immutable map in scala out of an existing Map

Tags: scala, maps

I thought this was going to be relatively straightforward. 
So I will explain:

I have a Map as under: This what I tried in the REPL

```
scala> val entriesList = List(("tPolicyId" -> "MasterCard"), ("SSN" -> "0"), ("MasterCard" -> "3"));
entriesList: List[(String, String)] = List((tPolicyId,MasterCard), (US SSN,0), (MasterCard,3))
```

I then convert the list to a Map as below.

```
scala> val entriesMap = entriesList.toMap
entriesMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> MasterCard,SSN -> 0, MasterCard -> 3)
```

So far so good. Now what I want to accomplish is a way to iterate over this Map, have a guard condition or a predicate as: **if the function I use to iterate over this Map encounters a key called tPolicyMap, please return or yield a new immutable Map, newMap that looks like this:**

```
  ***newMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> MasterCard)***
```

I thought this was going to be easy and the below represents all my failed attempts so far.

```
    scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if entry.contains("tPolicyId")) yield  entry
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if entry.contains("tPolicyId")) yield  entry
                                                                   ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  entry
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  entry
                                                                     ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
                                                                     ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if ( entry.contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
                                                                      ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if ( entry contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if ( entry contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  (entry)
                                                                      ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if entry contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  entry
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if entry contains("tPolicyId"))) yield  entry
                                                                                                   ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if entry contains("tPolicyId")) yield  entry
<console>:10: error: value contains is not a member of (String, String)
       val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap; if entry contains("tPolicyId")) yield  entry
                                                                    ^

scala> val tPolicyMap = for (entry <- entriesMap) yield  entry
tPolicyMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> MasterCard/Diner's Club U
S Number, US SSN -> 0, MasterCard -> 3)

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.contains("tPolicyId")
tPolicyEntry: Boolean = true

scala> val tPolicyEntry = if (entriesMap.contains("tPolicyId")) yield entriesMap
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyEntry = if (entriesMap.contains("tPolicyId")) yield entriesMap
                                                                                  ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = for(entry <- entriesMap; if entry == "tPolicyId" yield entry
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but 'yield' found.
       val tPolicyEntry = for(entry <- entriesMap; if entry == "tPolicyId" yield entry
                                                                                             ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = for(entry <- entriesMap; if entry == "tPolicyId") yield entry
<console>:10: warning: comparing values of types (String, String) and String using `==' will always yield false
       val tPolicyEntry = for(entry <- entriesMap; if entry == "tPolicyId") yield entry
                                                                     ^
tPolicyEntry: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map()

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry
                                                                                                      ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)))) yield entry
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)))) yield entry
                                                                                                     ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry)
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry)
                                                                                                      ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry))
<console>:1: error: illegal start of simple expression
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry)) yield entry))
                                                                                                      ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry) yield entry))
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but 'yield' found.
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry) yield entry))
                                                                                                     ^

scala> val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry) yield entry)
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but 'yield' found.
       val tPolicyEntry = entriesMap.keys.foreach( (entry) => if(entriesMap.contains(entry) yield entry)
```

As you can see, I have tried unsuccessfully to use filter, yield, foreach, for, etc in various combinations. I still don't get it/

So, I have tried hard, and I am probably making some fundamentally naive mistakes.

If someone can help me figure out how to get this Map I want, I would much appreciate the learning experience

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as simple as

```
 entriesMap.filter { case (k, _) => k == "tPolicyId" }
 //> res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> MasterCard)
```

Or simply

```
 entriesMap filterKeys { _ == "tPolicyId"  }
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit. That is a very brief and elegant solution. I will try out out in Repl..

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking imperatively (iterate, compare, if matching then do this) as opposed the higher level that the Scala immutable collections leans towards:

```
// get looks up value from a map using the key (fast)
// will give you an Option[String] back - 
// Some(value) if the key exists, None if it doesn't
tpPolicyMap.get("tPolicyId").fold[Map[String, String]](
  // result for None - no "tPolicyId"-key in the source map
  Map.empty
)(value => 
  // found, create a new map with that entry
  Map("tPolicyId" -> value)
)
```

Comment: Note that this will not have to go through each entry in the map  (which the other solutions will) but will use the key hashing built into map which is constant time lookup.

Comment: That is so true. I am thinking completely imperatively. Thanks for your answer. I will try it out in my REPL and let you know.

Comment: Actually  I think this is a much more elegant solution. Algorithmically speaking, this is better?

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` solution is good. You can also do `collect` which might be handy if you plan to do a `map` after the `filter`

```scala
entriesMap.collect{ case(k, v) if k == "tPolicyId" => (k, s"test${v}") } // example instead of plain (k, v)
// scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> testMasterCard)
```

Is the same as:

```scala
(entriesMap filterKeys { _ == "tPolicyId"  }).map((kv) => (kv._1, s"test${kv._2}"))

// scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(tPolicyId -> testMasterCard)
```